# Why does my table head get a color when css is empty and I dont style the table in my html?

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

Alright, so my page looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the marked "Detailansicht Telefonnummer" has a blue background and I dont know where it is coming from. The css file is empty and it is an Angular component. Any help is appreciated.

phonenumber-detail.html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{{id}}</td>

    </tr>

</table>

<br>
<button (click)="blockPhoneNumber((phonenumber))">Manuell sperren</button>
<br>
<button (click)="unblockPhoneNumber((phonenumber))">Entsperren</button>
<br>
<button (click)="reservePhoneNumber((phonenumber))">Reservieren</button>

<table style='text-align:left'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th colspan="2"><h3>Detailansicht Telefonnummer</h3></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width= '200'><b>Nummer:</b></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Typ:</b></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Letzte Änderung:</b></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Geändert durch:</b></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br />

<button (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 0 20px">zurück</button>
<button (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 0 20px">blockieren</button>
<button (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 0 20px">reservieren</button>
```

Comment: Did you try inspecting the element using chrome devtools?

Comment: have to reload the page with ctrl + shift + R

Comment: Page is reloaded. It reloads after making change cause I started the server with "--poll=2000"

Comment: Does this happen everytime you reload the page?

Comment: I just checked it with developer tools. Somehow my h3 is styled blue. But nowhere in my css files I style a h3!

Comment: I highlighted it with the mouse so you can see there is text behind the color

Comment: Under the styles tab in devtools, you will be able to see what all css is affecting the h3 element. Can you see any class with `background` or `background-color` attribute?

Comment: Oh, I understand. The inspector should give you the file's name and the line where this behavior happens. It could be some node_module's files(?)

Comment: Okay, thanks to NiK648 I could find the cause. Apparently, thead has a background-color. So I checked why. Apparently it is predefined and my first guess would be, that I am using a ui-kit in the company and this ui-kit defined already the thead with a blue color. I will just overwrite the value then. If I am wrong, correct me please. Thanks to you guys!

Comment: Yep, you can simply use `!important` to override the default value.

Comment: Okay I have just overwritten the thead in the css file. Now it works

Comment: Jacopo what u mean? You can write an answer, that would be more suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table th h3 {
  background: transparent !important;
}

table th h3.bg-default {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
solution 1-
<th colspan="2"><h3>Detailansicht Telefonnummer</h3></th>
<hr>
solution 2-
<th colspan="2"><h3 class="bg-default">Detailansicht Telefonnummer</h3></th>
```

Try like this...